# Alter table & Add UNIQUE key results in an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called `Animal`. `AnimalId` is the primary key & I wanted to set  the column `AnimalType_id` as UNIQUE (I have an `AnimalType` table and need to set a foreign key here)

```
ALTER TABLE Animal
ADD UNIQUE Animal.AnimalType_id int
```

There already is data in both tables, because of that I can't drop the table.

This however results in an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: @ Conrad Frix Yes error is what ?

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe What is the error message you see when you try to add the unique constraint?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) for how to add a table constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE Animal ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Animal_AnimalTypeId UNIQUE (AnimalType_id)
```

It sounds like AnimalType_id is a foreign key so I just wanted to check you understood that by making this column unique, you're making the relationship one-one - you'll only be able to have one animal of each type.

Since you're getting an error adding the unique constraint, I'm going to suggest that you actually want a foreign key instead of a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Animal
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Animal_AnimalType
    FOREIGN KEY
    (
        AnimalType_id
    )
    REFERENCES AnimalType
    (
        id
    )
```

I've had to guess at the name of the AnimalType table name and it's primary key column name - please change these if they are incorrect.

Comment: And even better: **name** your unique constraint! `ALTER TABLE Animal ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Animal_AnimalTypeId UNIQUE (AnimalType_id)`

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'.

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe Sorry, a constraint name is required when the `CONSTRAINT` keyword is used. Answer edited; and thanks to @marc_s.

Comment: Already i have a primarykey in this table.. i got this error > Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Animal' and the index name 'UQ_Animal_AnimalTypeId'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe Are you sure you want that column to be unique? As I mentioned in my answer, it will make the relationship 1-1 and your error suggests that's not what you want.

Comment: @chathuraRanasinghe: obviously, your data already has duplicates - you cannot create a UNIQUE constraint on a column that contains duplicate values. Fix those duplicates - and **then** you can create the unique constraint

Answer (score 2):

If you get into the habit of giving names to all objects (even constraints) that you create, you will have easier time later when you need to disable, drop, or alter the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Animal ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Animal_Type UNIQUE (AnimalType_id)
```

It is also possible to get a more flexible constraint-like effect from creating a unique index.

Comment: Already i have a primarykey in this table.. i got this error > Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Animal' and the index name 'UQ_Animal_AnimalTypeId'. The duplicate key value is (1). –

Comment: Got it now.  `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` are two different things.   `ALTER TABLE Animal
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Animal_Type
FOREIGN KEY (AnimalType_id)
REFERENCES Animal_Type(AnimalType_id)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE Animal
ADD COLUMN AnimalType_id int;
```

Comment: no actually.already i have a coloumn called AnimalType_id .. I wanted to SET that id as a UNIQUE key

Answer (score 0):

It seems the data in the column is not unique. 
when you create a unique constraint on a column, you can not have any duplicate entries (you can have at most one null)

Comment: actually this is data transfer from 1 db to another db with adding more coloumns.thats why

Answer (score -1):

try this

> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (column_name)